# Creating computed class properties from array

Tags: typescript, literals, computed-properties

I have an array of string literals that I'd like to use as property names for a class.

```js
const propNames = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
```

I would like to create a class like

```js
class Test {
    [name in typeof propNames[number]]: any;
}
```

But this gives the errors (in WebStorm inspection):

```
TS1166: A computed property name in a class property declaration must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
TS2361: The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.
TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I can instead define a type with those properties like

```js
type Test = {
    [name in typeof propNames[number]]: any;
}
```

But I don't know a way of turning this into a class with those properties.

I have an extra question that I don't think is possible currently, but could I create those property names by concatenating another string literal to them?

```js
type Test = {
    [name + 'Prop' in typeof propNames[number]]: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this (including the extra question) by defining intermediate types and using them like namespaces:

```js
const propNames = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;

// using DOM types for demonstration
type Canvases {
    [name in typeof propNames[number]]?: HTMLCanvasElement;
}
type Contexts {
    [name in typeof propNames[number]]?: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
}

// define class
class Test {
    canvases: Canvases = {};
    ctxs: Contexts = {};
}

// now access on instances
const t = new Test();
t.canvases.a; // HTMLCanvasElement
t.ctxs.b;     // CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a type, and then use it via:

```
type Test = {
    [key: TEST]: any;
}
```

where TEST is the type. I've never ventured into doing this but I know it works for primitive types.

Hope it gets you where you need to go!

Comment: I'd like to define the properties inside a class rather than a type (which I can already do). Also, this seems to be a syntax error? `TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`